# WordPress4.9.10 wp_options table size getting huge under PHP5.6

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My client has WordPress4.9.10 and WP `wp_options` table size getting huge under PHP5.6 & mySQL version 5.0.11.
The row count is `192` but the table size gose up unlimitedly like `1.2GB`.
I calculated the size of tables using the following sql.

```sql
SELECT 
     table_schema as `Database`, 
     table_name AS `Table`, 
     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

And seems like the table size is getting larger about 50MB every day.
But no new rows are added.

I ran the SQL below to delete unnecessary `_transient_%` records but no luck at all.

```sql
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_%';
```

I also disabled and delete unnecessary plugins and themes.
The WP currently has the plugins below:

- All In One SEO Pack (3.1.1)
- Contact Form 7 (5.1.3)
- Custom Post Type Generator (2.4.2)
- Custom Post Type UI (1.6.2)
- PDF Embedder (4.2)
- TablePress (1.9.2)
- WP Olive Cart Pro (3.2.6)
- WP-PageNavi (2.93)

Anyone has idea what's happening and how to fix this??

best,

Comment: This should not be due to transient as from WP 4.9 expired transients are cleaned up by core itself.

Comment: @Nilambar Yes, it does not fix my problem at all. `wp_options` table normally less than 1MB in my case.

Comment: So, check which table is consuming that much space. From that you can find out.

Comment: @Nilambar `wp_options` table is the one getting huge space day by day

Comment: Have you checked which `option_name` is getting huge?

Comment: @Nilambar no `option_name` is not too huge. 
I find out how to normalize the table with phpMyAdmin UI. I click the "Flush the table (FLUSH)" in "Operations" tab. It fixes the size of `wp_options` table.
However, this is just one-time temporary fix... I still need to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Gargantuan Wordpress Database Fix

#### Bind the remote MySQL port to your local port 3304

(Replace `username@example.com` below with the correct user and hostname; if you use a password to connect with SSH, remove `-i server.pem`)

Run this locally to bind to the remote port:

```
ssh -i server.pem -L 3304:127.0.0.1:3306 username@example.com
```

#### Connect With MySQL Workbench

Use the details below to connect:

```
hostname: localhost
port: 3304
user: root
password: <database-password-here>
```

#### Check `wp_options` Table Size

Run this query in MySQL Workbench and look at the size of the top row:

```
SELECT
  table_schema AS `Database`,
  table_name AS `Table`,
  round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`
FROM information_schema.TABLES
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

#### Delete Transient Entries

(Replace `<database-name>` in the commands below with the name of your database; the default is `wordpress`)

Run this query to delete transient records:

```
DELETE FROM <database-name>.wp_options
WHERE option_name LIKE '%transient%';
```

#### Optimize `wp_options` Table

In the terminal, run these in this order, twice (it will ask for the password each command):

```
mysqlcheck -p -c <database_name> wp_options
mysqlcheck -p -o <database_name> wp_options
mysqlcheck -p -a <database_name> wp_options
```

#### Verify `wp_options` Table Size

Go back to MySQL Workbench and double-check table size:

```
SELECT
  table_schema AS `Database`,
  table_name AS `Table`,
  round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`
FROM information_schema.TABLES
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

#### Purge Database Binary Logs

Run this query to purge the binary logs:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```